# How to create nine patch for this image with 2 shapes in the corners?

Tags: android, nine-patch

[image: 9 patch with 2 corners]

I am finding difficult to to create 9 patch of below image without distorting square and quarter circle. I know if I reduce the height of both shapes ( which is currently half of main rectangle itself ) , it will not be that difficult.

Is there any way around to create 9 patch for such images without reducing their height ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only possibility that I see is to make height of left thing + height of right thing 1px smaller than height of whole image, and than to make 9-patch stretch just on that pixel in middle.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for this image because there is not even one pixel between the square and quarter circle (on the vertical axis).

If you enlarge the height of the image with 1-2 pixels (depends on density), putting the square and quarter circle a bit apart on the vertical axis. Then mark those new "center pixels" as stretchable.

Comment: Thank you Shell, going to use your and Vladimir's suggestion.. accepted Vladimir's answer only because it was 1 min earlier than yours..

Answer (score 0):

You could instead have two separate images (one with a square and one with a circle) and use two views instead of one to show them. That way you could still have a narrow image where the square and circle both are almost as tall as the image.

Comment: But how 2 views will be used ? I intend to use them in Navigation Drawer background ...

Comment: You can have other views in your drawer. But since you don't need this image to work even if the height is very small, the answer by @VladimirJovanovic is probably better for you.